# paypal sandbox is not working for testing, i got this messege again and again

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

"Your card was declined by the issuing bank. Try a different card or contact your card issuer with questions."

i couldnot proceed to paypal sandbox payment for testing . how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Go to [Credit Card Generator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/creditCardGenerator/) and create a card for testing
- Go to [PayPal Developer - Accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/) and create 'personal' account with a credit card

Answer (score 0):

There are two areas(Paypal and PayPal Checkout) in the Wordpress backend where you set the paypal environment to sandbox. I had set only one area. Because of this, I was unknowingly targeting the live PayPal environment.